# Saving and Loading Pytorch Model Checkpoint for inference not working

Tags: python-3.x, lstm, pytorch

I have a trained model using LSTM. The model is trained on **GPU** (On Google COLABORATORY).
I have to save the model for inference; which I will run on **CPU**.
Once trained, I saved the model checkpoint as follows:

```
torch.save({'model_state_dict': model.state_dict()},'lstmmodelgpu.tar')
```

And, for inference, I loaded the model as :

```
# model definition
vocab_size = len(vocab_to_int)+1 
output_size = 1
embedding_dim = 300
hidden_dim = 256
n_layers = 2

model = SentimentLSTM(vocab_size, output_size, embedding_dim, hidden_dim, n_layers)

# loading model
device = torch.device('cpu')
checkpoint = torch.load('lstmmodelgpu.tar', map_location=device)
model.load_state_dict(checkpoint['model_state_dict'])
model.eval()
```

But, it is raising the following error:

```
model.load_state_dict(checkpoint['model_state_dict'])
  File "workspace/envs/envdeeplearning/lib/python3.5/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 719, in load_state_dict
    self.__class__.__name__, "\n\t".join(error_msgs)))
RuntimeError: Error(s) in loading state_dict for SentimentLSTM:
    Missing key(s) in state_dict: "embedding.weight". 
    Unexpected key(s) in state_dict: "encoder.weight".
```

Is there anything I missed while saving the checkpoint?

Comment: Are you using `DataParallel`?

Comment: @harshit_k, No, I am not using DataParallel. I have followed the tutorial : https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/saving_loading_models.html#saving-loading-a-general-checkpoint-for-inference-and-or-resuming-training

Comment: Don't know why the error but you may still try the solution given in https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/solved-keyerror-unexpected-key-module-encoder-embedding-weight-in-state-dict/1686/4?u=kharshit or use `model.module.load_state_dict(checkpoint['model_state_dict'])`. But, I'm not certain any of this would work.

Answer (score 3):

There are two things to be considered here.

1. You mentioned that you're training your model on GPU and using it for inference on CPU, so u need to add a parameter **map_location** in **load** function passing **torch.device('cpu')**.
2. There is a mismatch of state_dict keys (indicated in your ouput message), which might be caused by some missing keys or having more keys in *state_dict* you are loading than the model u are using currently. And for it you have to add a parameter **strict**  with value **False**  in the **load_state_dict** function. This will make method to ignore the mismatch of keys.

Side note : Try to use extension of pt or pth for checkpoint files as it is a convention .